# Algorithm which checks for ascending descending order

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I'm beginner in Java, so hope you'll understand it. I tried a few different ways, but it always has a problem with the logic: it cannot save a variable and check it in while loop or cannot go right through the if else statements. There is supposed to be some trick and I cannot find it.

For example:

If input is 1, 47, 89, 98, 165,256,300 **0**, it stops and prints *"End of the program, numbers been entered in regular order"*.

If input is 86,75,32,11,**0**, it stops and prints *"End of the program, numbers been entered in reversed order"*.

If input is 43, 54,11,6,7,45,44,44,44,56,33**0**, it stops and prints *"End of the program, numbers been entered in mixed or same order"*

Here is the updated version of the code(2):

```
        boolean  mixed;
        boolean up  =true;
        boolean down =true; 
        int numToAdd;
        System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
         int previousNum = input.nextInt();

        do {
             System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
            numToAdd = input.nextInt();
             if (numToAdd == 0) break;
             
             

            if (numToAdd > previousNum ) {
             up = true;


            }
            if (numToAdd < previousNum) {
                 down = true;
            }

            mixed =  !up && !down; 
            previousNum = numToAdd;
        } while (numToAdd != 0);

        if (up = true ) {
            System.out.println("End of the program, numbers been entered in regular order");
        }

        if (down = true) {
            System.out.println("End of the program, numbers been entered in reversed order");
        }
        if (mixed = true) {
            System.out.println("End of the program, numbers been entered in mixed or same order");
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249554/discussion-on-question-by-brandon-nolan-algorithm-which-checks-for-ascending-des).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't want to give the O/P a complete answer. If we did that, the O/P could hand in code he / she  didn't write and doesn't understand. Instead, we want to guide the O/P toward a solution. We feel the O/P will learn more that way.

I'm looking at the 2nd version of the O/P code.

There are at least 3 problems with the 2nd attempt.

(1) It appears the code intends zero to be a sentinel value. When the user enters zero, the program is supposed to exit the loop and print the results. The problem is, the code processes the sentinel value before the terminating condition in the `do { } while ()` loop is reached. This could make a strictly ascending sequence appear to be a mixed sequence.

There are several ways this can be fixed, but one has already been suggested in the comments:

```
do {
     System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
     numToAdd = input.nextInt();
     if (numToAdd == 0) break;
```

(2) The variable `loopFor` is written as if it is a sum of the numbers entered. The sum of the numbers entered is irrelevant to what the program is supposed to be doing. From the rest of the code, it seems `loopFor` is intended to be the previous value entered.

To fix this, the `loopFor +=  numToAdd;` statement should be deleted. The statement `loopFor = numToAdd` should be added to the code, but *in a different place*. The proper place is *after* all comparison of `loopFor` with `numToAdd` has been completed.

Refactor suggestion: Rename `loopFor` to `previousNum`.

However, that change still leaves a problem. The variable `loopFor` needs an initial value. Because the programmer doesn't know if the user will enter an increasing sequence or a decreasing sequence, the initial value can be neither an artificially high value nor an artificially low value.

I'll leave it to the O/P to figure out how to solve that.

(3) The way the `boolean` values `up`, `down`, `mixed` are managed is not reliable. If, for example, `up` is set to `true`, it can later be set to `false`. Still later, it can be set to `true` again.

These should each be set to an initial value. Upon detection of an appropriate condition, the value is flipped, and is never set to the initial value again.

My suggestion is set `up` and `down` to `true` **only** at the beginning of the program. When a sequence of numbers is detected that shows one of them to be `false`, set that one to `false`.

Note that "mixed" can be detected at the end by something like this:

```
  boolean mixed =  !up && !down;
```

So, that variable isn't really needed.

Again, I'll leave it to the O/P how to make the change.

Comment: I also feel that is the situation is mixed, then this will not change and the program can simply print and exit and that point (but maybe I am misreading the requirements).

Comment: I tried a follow code with suggestions u gave me but its still not working porperly.

Comment: @BrandonNolan Create  new question with a copy of your most recent code. In the question body, reference this question.  Add a comment to this question referencing the new question.

Comment: check it out now

Comment: i cannot create a new question since you guys banned me from doing this. so i just updated the body of this question

Comment: I didn't ban you. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Two of the three problems I mentioned in the code still exist.  When you find a condition for which `up` should be set to `false`, the *only* thing that should follow is setting `up` to `false`. Don't set the values of the other `boolean` values. The same with `down`.

Comment: There is no initial literal value for `previousNum` that will cause your program to work. What you need to do is set it to the first number the user enters, and then promptly move to the 2nd number. The easiest way to do that is to input `previousNum` before the loop.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer or we don't understand each other or your suggestions are not sounds clearly for me. I've just updated the code you can take a look again
Now its printing all the outputs no matter what, its not behavior i need.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer more than it i still dont see here a kinda switcher which will make a logic follow and check twice: if first and second input are reversing order then keep down true till user will not input 0 or if user will not input number bigger than previous. Same with increasing number. I dont want to spend around the week with this stupid task just because im not allowed use other instruments like arrays and methods. im just simply asking for the answer and dont think that it should take so much time to answer it.

Comment: In the loop, don't set `up` to `true`. Don't set `down` to `true`. Set them only to `false`.  For example `if (numToAdd <= previousNum) up = false;`

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer bruh you're fixed this! Thanks a lot fo help, ill update my code now

Comment: You're welcome.  You might want to test your program to see what happens if the first number the user enters is `0`.

Comment: By the way, `if (up = true )` should be `if (up == true)`.  Even better is `if (up)`.

Comment: it was problem in the end though because after loops its ran in debug and somehow changed all saved booleans to true. Ive realized thats is because in the end its been set to the up = true and down = true  instead of up == true and down == true
also mixed part didnt worked properly because when its been placed as mixed = true it's simply been placed as new value, but doing the same with mixed like with the previous and pass mixed == true didnt worked and somehow there was error  "local variable mixed may not have been initialized. So i passed the same as in  the loop: mixed = !up && !down

Comment: So really thanks for the help. By the way its my first time here on stackoverflow asking the questions so i could tell that community  greeted me quite cool.

Comment: You don't need the variable `mixed`.  Instead of `if (mixed = !up && !down)`, use `if ( ! up && ! down)`.

Comment: "There is no initial literal value for `previousNum` that will cause your program to work.  ..." -- Not quite true. An alternative is to initialize it to zero, and then make comparisons to `numToAdd` dependent on `previousNum` not being zero. One way, for example, would be to add `if (previousNum == 0) continue;`.